# Problem with Loading Global Variable in Production Build In Angular Project

Tags: angular, global-variables, angular7, environment, production

Trying to load environment from `js` file to having dynamic environment, independent from build based on [this article](https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/).

`env.js` file added to project like this:

```
(function (window) {
  window.__env = window.__env || {};

  // API url
  window.__env.apiUrl = 'http://dev.your-api.com';

  // Whether or not to enable debug mode
  // Setting this to false will disable console output
  window.__env.enableDebug = true;
}(this));
```

Then i add script to index.html to load js file:

```
<script src="env.js"></script>
```

I use global variable this way:

```
console.log(window['__env']);
```

I serve the project everything works fine, I Build the project (regular build with `ng build`) everything is fine too,

But when i build with `ng build --prod`, the global variable is null,

how to tell webpack to there is a global variable that you should brig it in without using services?

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a JSON file to read Environment dynamically build independent:

This line Load env.json in AppModule inside APP_Initilizer:

```
export function init_app(appLoadService: AppInitService) {
  return () => appLoadService.init("assets/env.json");
}
```

Note: dont forget the provide part:

```
  providers: [
    EnvServiceProvider,
    AppInitService,
    AuthenticationService,
    // TabGuard,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: init_app,
      deps: [AppInitService],
      multi: true,
    }
    // ...
    ]
```

The AppInitService:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppInitService {

  // This is the method you want to call at bootstrap
  // Important: It should return a Promise
  public init(path:string) {
    return from(
        fetch(path).then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
        })
      ).pipe(
        map((config) => {
        window['__env'] = config;
        return
      })).toPromise();
  }
}
```

Then use an environment provider to provide envs:

```
import { EnvService } from './env.service';

export const EnvServiceFactory = () => {
  // Create env
  const env = new EnvService();

  // Read environment variables from browser window
  const browserWindow = window || {};
  const browserWindowEnv = browserWindow['__env'] || {};

  // Assign environment variables from browser window to env
  // In the current implementation, properties from env.js overwrite defaults from the EnvService.
  // If needed, a deep merge can be performed here to merge properties instead of overwriting them.
  for (const key in browserWindowEnv) {
    if (browserWindowEnv.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      env[key] = window['__env'][key];
    }
  }
  return env;
};

export const EnvServiceProvider = {
  provide: EnvService,
  useFactory: EnvServiceFactory,
  deps: [],
};
```

Use env provider like this:

```
  env: any;
  constructor(
    public envService: EnvService
  ) {
    this.env = this.envService;
  }
```